# Merging a dynamic number of collections together

Tags: laravel, collections, merge, eloquent

I'm working on my first laravel project: a family tree.  I have 4 branches of the family, each with people/families/images/stories/etc.  A given user on the website will have access to everything for 1, 2, or 4 of these branches of the family (I don't want to show a cousin stuff for people they're not related to).

So on various pages I want the collections from the controller to contain stuff based on the given user's permissions. Merge *seems* like the right way to do this.

I have scopes to get people from each branch of the family, and in the following example I also have a scope for people with a birthday this month. In order to show the right set of birthdays for this user, I can get this by merging each group individually if they have access.

Here's what my function would look like if I showed everyone in all 4 family branches:

```
public function get_birthday_people()
{
    $user =  \Auth::user();

    $jones_birthdays = Person::birthdays()->jones()->get();
    $smith_birthdays = Person::birthdays()->smith()->get();
    $lee_birthdays = Person::birthdays()->lee()->get();
    $brandt_birthdays = Person::birthdays()->brandt()->get();

    $birthday_people  = $jones_birthdays 
        ->merge($smith_birthdays)
        ->merge($lee_birthdays )
        ->merge($brandt_birthdays );

    return $birthday_people;
```

My challenge: I'd like to modify it so that I check the user's access and only add each group of people accordingly.  I'm imagining something where it's all the same as above except I add conditionals like this:

```
        if($user->jones_access) {
$jones_birthdays = Person::birthdays()->jones()->get();
}
     else{
$jones_birthdays =NULL;
}
```

But that throws an error for users without access because I can't call merge on NULL (or an empty array, or the other versions of 'nothing' that I tried).

**What's a good way to do something like this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if($user->jones_access) {
   $jones_birthdays = Person::birthdays()->jones()->get();
}
else{
   $jones_birthdays = new Collection;
}
```

Better yet, do the merge in the condition, no else required.

```
$birthday_people = new Collection;
if($user->jones_access) {
   $birthday_people->merge(Person::birthdays()->jones()->get());
}
```

Comment: Yes this is it!!!  Both ways work, and the second one is shorter/cleaner.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Merge helper overwrites elements with same ids: https://medium.com/@tadaspaplauskas/quick-tip-laravel-eloquent-collections-merge-gotcha-moment-e2a56fc95889

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want your Eloquent query to only return the relevant data for the user requesting it. It doesn't make sense to query Lee birthdays when a Jones person is accessing that page.

So what you will wind up doing is something like

`$birthdays = App\Person::where('family', $user->family)->get();`

This pulls in Persons where their `family` property is equal to the family of the current user.

This probably does not match the way you have your relationships right now, but hopefully it will get you on the right track to getting them sorted out.

If you really want to go ahead with a bunch of queries and checking for authorization, read up on the [authorization](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization) features of Laravel. It will give let you assign abilities to users and check them easily.

Comment: thanks Brynn!  Users have access to up to 4 family branches so I may need some array or something... And thanks for the link about authorization- it looks like that's more geared toward actions rather than filtering the data, but I'm sure it'll be helpful!  In the meantime the other answer has me up and running so I'm good to go.  Thanks!